# Using gcov when application is moved

Tags: code-coverage, gcov

I have looked at many postings but cannot find a related one.  I have a large Eclipse project with the following layout...

```
Source\
    Operations\ 1.cpp, 2.cpp, 3.cpp
    Commands\ a.cpp, b.cpp, c.cpp
    Listeners\ x.cpp, y.cpp, z.cpp

Debug\
    Operations\ 1.o, 2.o, 3.o
    Commands\ a.o, b.o, c.o
    Listeners\ x.o, y.o, z.o
    APP
```

But now I have to move `APP` to `~/config/` where all my required configuration files live and I get no `.gc*` files.

If I run the `APP` in the `Debug` directory, the proper `*.gcda` and `*.gcno` files are created.
But I cannot run from there since I require all my configuration files.

I have tried setting `$GCOV_PREFIX` to `~/config` but still nothing.

I tried a really simple gcov example in a test directory and it worked fine, when everything was in the same directory.  So I know it's not the compiler.

Comment: You can use -fprofile-generate="path" flag when you are compiling your program. This will generate the .gcda files at the path provided. Now you run your program in the config folder , this will generate your gcda files in the path provided. Copy the gcno files into the config folder as well. Now run gcov and you may get the coverage report.